# react functional component render twice after setState in the effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

i wrote the simple code as follows

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(2);
  }, [count]);

  console.info("render: ", count);
  return <div>{count}</div>;
}
```

the console output as

```
render:  1
render:  2
render:  2
```

why "render:2" output twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are unconditionally updating state that you are using as a dependency.

This behavior isn't unexpected.

See [Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the [Object.is comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with `useMemo`.

The `count` is 1 on the initial render, the first log.
`useEffect` hook runs and enqueues a state update and the update is processed.

The `count` is 2 on the next render, the second log.
`count` state value updated so `useEffect` hook callback runs and enqueues another state update to the same value and the update is processed.

The `count` is still 2 on the next render, the third log.
`count` state hasn't changed so the `useEffect` hook callback isn't triggered.